# How to run google test-analytics project on appEngine using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, google-app-engine

I am working on google test-analytics project and I am able to build the project successfully using maven through command line and deploy on google appEngine locally.But I couldn't figure out how to deploy the project on appengine using eclipse. when I right click on the project, Its not showing any option to "run on appEngine". 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Follow [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven#uploading_your_app_to_production_app_engine) documentation.

> To upload an app created with the the appengine-skeleton-archetype:
>
> 1. Change directory to the top level of your project (for example, myapp)
>      and invoke Maven as follows:
>
>    `mvn appengine:update`
> 2. You will be prompted for an authorization code in the terminal window
>      and your web browser will launch with a consent screen which you must
>      accept in order to be authorized. Follow the prompts to copy any codes
>      from the browser to the command line.